# How to enable absolute imports in eslint when extending airbnb?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint

I found [this](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/no-absolute-path.md) but I can't seem to figure out what to do. How can I change my .eslintrc file so it ignores absolute imports of React components. I get the `Unable to resolve path to module 'products/whatever/routing'.eslint(import/no-unresolved)` error when trying to import something.

Also, I have ./src as a baseUrl in jsconfig.json

Comment: Just find the rule and set it to "off" in .eslintrc.If this aproach doesnt work,try https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import.

Answer (score 2):

This solved the issue:

```
  settings: {
'import/resolver': {
  node: {
    paths: ['src']
  }
 }
}
```